# undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Attempting to utilize ActiveStorage for a simple image upload form. It creates successfully, but upon submission it throws an error:

```
undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? load
```

This is the block it wants me to look at:

```
    @comment = Comment.create! params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    @comment.image.attach(params[:comment][:image])
    redirect_to comments_path 
  end
```

This is in the full controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.create! params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    @comment.image.attach(params[:comment][:image])
    redirect_to comments_path 
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

What should actually happen is it takes you to the page to view the upload. Here:

```
# new.html.erb

   <%= form_with model: @comment, local: true  do |form| %>
   <%= form.text_area :content %><br><br>
    <%= form.file_field :image %><br>
   <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>

 # show.html.erb
   <%= image_tag @comment.image %>
```

Here's the comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

Error in the log:

```
 app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:12:in `create'
 Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-15 21:30:23 -0400
 Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",             "authenticity_token"=>"Al2SdLm1r6RWXQ6SrKNdUTWscSJ4/ha3h8C3xl6GvUsDhBGHkiesvGgyjL         5E1B1eyRUrYyjovFTQaGKwAZ1wtw==", "comment"=>{"content"=>"fdfdfdsdf", "image"=>#       <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb3d36d8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/tduke     /AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20180715-3328-10frg81.png>,       @original_filename="9c6f46a506b9ddcb318f3f9ba34bcb27.png",       @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;    name=\"comment[image]\"; filename=\"9c6f46a506b9ddcb318f3f9ba34bcb27.png     \"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 468ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)

 NoMethodError (undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
```

Did you mean?  load):

Comment: Do you get any errors in `Comment.create!1 ? and it is standard practice to move your permit method into a private method.

Comment: What line does this happen on?

Comment: @JoshBrody Line 9

Comment: Line 9 of what?

Comment: Lol sorry. Long day. It happens on        `@comment.image.attach(params[:comment][:image])`

Comment: what does comment.rb look like?

Comment: Attached it to the original post for better formatting

Comment: @T.Duke See my answer and let me know how that goes.

Comment: @JoshBrody Yep. It throws the same error.

Comment: do a full text search for `upload` in your project, and tell us where it's occurring, and what it's doing - is there an `upload` method in the `Image` model that's running as an `after_save` or something? You need to provide more detail for us to be able to fix your issue

Comment: Show the full contents of your `Comment` and `Image` model classes

Comment: Comment is in the original post However the search doesn't return anything. I did track this error down, I will post to the original post since it's too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :image))
@comment.save!
redirect_to comments_path
```

ActiveRecord is smart enough to know that `image` is a file that is handled by ActiveStorage, so you don't need to manually attach it. I'm guessing that because the record is already persisted and the image isn't there it's throwing a fit.

Also you should move your strong params to a method.

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :image)
end
```

And use like,

```
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
@comment.save!
redirect_to comments_path
```

Comment: So that still throws the error: `undefined method 'upload' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? load`

Comment: Try restarting your Rails server

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either unfortunately. I'm thinking it's a method either not working or not implemented. I added an error I found in the log to the post

Comment: If you want to pull this down, https://github.com/joshmn/tduke I just built it and made sure it works as an example using ActiveStorage. What version of Rails are you running? Have you installed the migrations for ActiveStorage?

Answer (score 53):

I  solved it by making sure that my Active Storage configuration in my environment file was set.

So, in `development.rb`, make sure the line

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

is present.

Comment: I just upgraded my old rails to 5.2 and error happened. This answer saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. Had same issue. Good luck that found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to 5.2 from 5.1, you may need to run

```
rails app:update
```

Make a backup first as this will ask you to override some files you might want to keep like `config/routes.rb`.

I had this issue and this resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error appeared only in the test environment.

For some reason, the Active Storage configuration was missing in my `test.rb`, so I added

```
config.active_storage.service = :test
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. I got it working by changing the `storage.yml` file so that development stores to `"tmp/storage"` instead of `"storage"`. Like this:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :region) %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket) %>
```